# Вопрос по поводу setState() в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте. Я хотел спросить по поводу поведения метода setState в react.
Как я понимаю, вызвав его, мы устанавливаем значение переменной компонента (например переменную color), затем автоматически вызывается метод render().
Допустим результаты render() зависят от переменной color. Но setState({color:"red"}), не меняет эту переменную мгновенно, и метод render вполне может получить старое значение color.
В таком случае получается запаздывание отображения на один ход. Как быть в таком случае?

Ниже я привел рабочий пример, для валидации формы.

1. Поле "логин" и "пароль" валидны если содержат 3 и более символа.
2. Поле "повтор пароля" валидно если оно равно полю "пароль" и если поле "пароль" валидно.
3. кнопка отправить активна если все текстовые поля валидны.

```js
class Input extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isValid: false};
        this.inputValueChanged = this.inputValueChanged.bind(this);
    }

    inputValueChanged(e) {
        var txt = e.target.value;
        this.state.isValid = txt.length >= 3;
        this.state.text = txt;
        this.props.checkToUnblockSubmit();
    }

    render() {
        return React.createElement('input', {
            className: "form-control",
            onChange: this.inputValueChanged,
            placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
            type: this.props.type,
            style: {borderColor: this.state.isValid ? "green" : "red"}
        }, null);
    }
}


class Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {repeatIsValid: false, allInputsValid: false};
        this.checkToUnblockSubmit = this.checkToUnblockSubmit.bind(this);
        this.saveRepeatValue = this.saveRepeatValue.bind(this);
        this.send = this.send.bind(this);
    }

    checkToUnblockSubmit() {
        this.state.repeatIsValid = this.refs.password.state.isValid && (this.refs.password.state.text === this.state.repeatText);
        this.state.allInputsValid = this.refs.login.state.isValid && this.refs.password.state.isValid && this.state.repeatIsValid;
        this.setState();
    }

    saveRepeatValue(e) {
        this.state.repeatText = e.target.value;
        this.checkToUnblockSubmit();
    }

    send() {
       console.log("здесь мы отправляем");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            React.createElement('div', null,

                React.createElement('div', {className: "form-group"},
                    React.createElement(Input, {
                        type: "text",
                        ref: "login",
                        placeholder: "логин",
                        checkToUnblockSubmit: this.checkToUnblockSubmit
                    }, null)),

                React.createElement('div', {className: "form-group"},
                    React.createElement(Input, {
                        type: "password",
                        ref: "password",
                        placeholder: "пароль",
                        checkToUnblockSubmit: this.checkToUnblockSubmit
                    }, null)),

                React.createElement('div', {className: "form-group"},
                    React.createElement('input', {
                        type: "password",
                        ref: "repeat",
                        className: "form-control",
                        placeholder: "повторить пароль",
                        style: {borderColor: this.state.repeatIsValid ? "green" : "red"},
                        onChange: this.saveRepeatValue
                    }, null)),

                React.createElement('div', {className: "form-group"},
                    React.createElement('button', {                        
                        className: this.state.allInputsValid ? "btn btn-success" : "btn btn-danger",
                        disabled: !this.state.allInputsValid,
                        onClick: this.send
                    }, 'отправить'))                    
            )
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Form, null, null),
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Такой вариант работал не корректно:

```
this.setState({
  repeatIsValid : this.refs.password.state.isValid && (this.refs.password.state.text === this.state.repeatText),
  allInputsValid : this.refs.login.state.isValid && this.refs.password.state.isValid && this.state.repeatIsValid
})
```

И поэтому для корректной работы мне пришлось сделать так :

```
 this.state.repeatIsValid = this.refs.password.state.isValid && (this.refs.password.state.text === this.state.repeatText);
 this.state.allInputsValid = this.refs.login.state.isValid && this.refs.password.state.isValid && this.state.repeatIsValid;
 this.setState();
```

правильно ли было так делать?

Comment: Мне лень разбираться в вашей портянке, поэтому напишу  комментарием а не ответом) 
Нет, неправильно. В-нулевых рекомендую использовать какую-нибудь готовую либу для форм а не велосипедить. Ручками с формами в реакте работать не оч удобно. У меня сейчас redux-forms

Comment: Во-первых setState - асинхронная операция. Это конечно весьма неочевидно если не читать документацию внимательно, а сразу бросаться в бой. Она приинмает вторым опциональным параметром колбек. Внимательно почитайте соответствующий раздел доки https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Во вторых в setState можно пробросить функцию от текущего состояния и пропсов, так удобнее зачастую https://medium.com/@shopsifter/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1

Comment: В третьих если вы уж хачите меняя this.state руками то хачьте семантично) Семантичным хаком сдесь было бы
Вместо this.setState(); было бы this.forceUpdate();

Comment: И в четвертых, мне любопытно, а почему Вы не используете jsx но при этом используете es6 классы? Это обусловлено отсутствием этапа сборки? (а классы то тогда почему используете?) Или jsx просто не нравится? Или просто для фиддла сделали а обычно у вас нормальный jsx?

Comment: Да это не проектный код, а просто для изучения react для себя. JSX не стал подключать, потому что показалось что babel-core много весит.

Comment: без jsx реакт использовать можно, но скорее "на всякий случай", это очень неудобно, я ни одного такого извращенца в продакшне не знаю)
babel-core обычно работает на этапе сборки на машине разработчика, на клиент  не уезжает и пофигу сколько он там весит. Можно конечно использовать babel-standalone на клиете, но делают это крайне редко.

Comment: _JSX не стал подключать, потому что показалось что babel-core много весит._ Причем здесь babel-core? JSX - часть React, и не имеет никакого отношения к babel.

Comment: но без подключения специальных библиотек (таких https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.min.js), браузер не понимает jsx синтаксис, (таких return <h1>hello world</h1>)

Comment: @fantastic рекомендую tsc (TypeScript Compiler). Он легче чем babel.

Comment: @fantastic и, кроме того, ни tsc, ни babel не нужно подключать на страницу. Это - утилиты для разработчика, а не скрипты для браузера.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но тогда топикстартеру гарантированно сложнее будет плясать с бубном если что-то пойдет не так. Связка с бабелем на порядок более распространенная, гуглить без понимания легче.

Comment: Зачем нужен setState() ? если я его вызываю, то я подразумеваю, сперва обновится state.поле, потом компонент перерисуется (с учетом обновленного поля).  
А происходит, что компонент перерисовывается, потом обновляется state.поле